# Grails Lookup Secured JNDI

Tags: grails, weblogic, datasource, jndi

I am using Weblogic 12c and have a DataSource with jndiName "myDataSource."

The dataSource allows lookup access to anyone and I can look it up normally by doing:

```
 dataSource{
      jndiName = "myDataSource"
 }
```

in the config files.

I then added some security settings to the dataSource which specify only a certain user or admins have access to perform lookup operations on the jndiName.

If I try to lookup the dataSource now I receive an exception that states anonymous user does not have lookup rights on the resource. (As expected)

My question is:
Does Grails have any functionality to handle lookup credentials or do I have to manually setup an initialContext with the correct credentials so the lookup is successful?

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone needs the solution this works:
Remove dataSource from config.groovy and use this in resources.groovy

```
jndiTemplate(org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate) { bean ->
    bean.scope = "prototype"
    environment = [
      "java.naming.factory.initial":"weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory",
      "java.naming.security.principal"  : "username",
      "java.naming.security.credentials": "password"
      ]
}

dataSource(org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean){
    jndiTemplate = ref(jndiTemplate)
    jndiName = "name"
    exposeAccessContext=true
}
```